# Invalid Meter Number and Now Authentication Failed

Tags: nopcommerce, fedex

I am using FedEx (Plugin) in nopCommerce.And fill all the Necessary Details.and got error message (meter number in invalid) but when i change the  url from **https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services**  to  **https://gateway.fedex.com:443/web-services** and now new error occur Authentication Failed. I check all the details
Twice.
And when i check  **admin-> system ->log**
and found the the follow Details. Now I Face the problem with Authentication Failed. If u solve this please tell me how.

Log 1:

Log Level :       Warning
Short message :   Shipping (FedEx). Authentication Failed
Full message:
IP address:       127.0.0.1
Customer:
Page URL:
Referrer URL:     /onepagecheckout
Created on:       9/15/2014 12:40:30 PM

Log 2 :
Log Level :          Warning 
Short message :     Resource string (messages.order.product(s).shippingaddress) is not found. Language ID = 1 
Full message: 
IP address:         127.0.0.1 
Customer:
Page URL:
Referrer URL:     /onepagecheckout 
Created on:       9/15/2014 1:02:52 PM

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that your using your FedEx production credentials (key, password, account, and meter) as your test credentials will not work in their production environment.

Second, try using 'https://ws.fedex.com:443/web-services' instead of 'https://gateway.fedex.com:443/web-services'.  From my understanding the 'gateway' endpoint is older.

Third, if your using the FedEx provided WSDL, you'll have to open and modify the endpoint binding located at the bottom on the WSDL file.